# how to use logging inside Gevent?

Tags: python, gevent

I have a code like:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__file__)

def func():
    print "1"
    log.debug("Printed")

g = gevent.spawn(func)
g.join()
```

but when I ran it my log doesn't show in shell. Any ideas? Is there a better way to do logging inside gevent based coroutines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is unrelated to gevent. You should configure [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) e.g.,

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s %(msg)s")
```

Comment: Thanks, I usually get away with just logging.basicConfig() but I guess it makes sense since that set lvl to NOTSET.